# Evento toggle_sidebar

Tags: javascript

Como saber se o `toggle_sidebar` esta ativado ou não ?

Eu utilizo este comando para ativar e desativar:

```
uib_sb.toggle_sidebar($(".uib_w_43"));
```

Comment: O que é esse método `toggle_sidebar()?` algum plugin? qual?

Comment: Não toggle_sidebar() é algo nativo do indexedb, serve para abrir uma sidebar e fecha-la.

Comment: Nativo do `indexedb`? o `indexedb` é uma base de dados local do browser...

Comment: Ops perdão do IntelXDK kkkk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`hasClass()`**](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) para saber se o elemento possui a classe a classe que o torna ativo, por exemplo:

```
if($('.uib_w_43').hasClass('.uib_bar_visible')){
   // Está ativo...
}
```

Ou pode fazer sem jQuery, usando [**`classlist#contains()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList):

```
var foo = document.querySelector('.uib_w_43');
if(foo.classList.contains('uib_bar_visible'){
  // Está ativo...
}
```

Comment: Na verdade não sei como funciona direitinho esta questão do toggle, o que sei que o mesmo que ativa desativa. no caso qual seria a classe, sabe me informar ?

Comment: Descobri que é `uib_bar_visible`, no caso como ficaria ?

Comment: @RenanRodrigues editei

Comment: o .foo é a div ?

Comment: Editei novamente. É o elemento que você quer verificar se tem a classe, creio que seja o `.uib_w_43`.

Comment: ok, irei verificar aqui e se der certinho aceito a resposta.